# How to derive time derivate of strain?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, stress-strain, data-analysis

Data

```
Time(s) Strain
-----------------
100 0.31
200 0.52
300 0.74
400 0.92
500 1.10
600 1.28
700 1.46
800 1.64
900 1.82
1000    2.00
```

I want to deduce $\dot{\gamma}$, time derivative of the shear strain.

The plot looks like this

[image]

There is a 2% uncertainty in fitting a line to the data:

```
gnuplot> fit f(x) 'timeSstrain.dat' via a 
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   a            
   0 3.8339867425e+06   0.00e+00  6.20e+02    1.000000e+00
   1 3.1685897105e+04  -1.20e+07  6.20e+01    9.280165e-02
   2 8.8349836349e-02  -3.59e+10  6.20e+00    2.172447e-03
   3 5.6727272730e-02  -5.57e+04  6.20e-01    2.081819e-03
   4 5.6727272727e-02  -5.57e-06  6.20e-02    2.081818e-03
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   a            

After 4 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 0.0567273
rel. change during last iteration : -5.57434e-11

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 9
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 0.0793916
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 0.00630303

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 0.00208182       +/- 4.046e-05    (1.944%)
```

I think it is not the tangent of the line.

I need to understand this for the deduction of viscosity from this data and shear stress data as a function of time. 
I am taking there just a tangent and considering $\dot{\gamma}$ as a constant, which I think is false.

**How can you describe this $\dot{\gamma}$?**

Comment: Why do you think it's not just the slope of the data? You have $\gamma(t)$ and it's a line, so the time derivative is most definitely just a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact a change in slope - you can see this when you fit a straight line through the data, then subtract it to look at the residuals:

[image]

It seems that the first three data points lie on a steeper curve than the remainder - as though something changed in the setup (did thing heat up?)

Residuals plots are an essential tool when you analyze data that "looks linear".

Comment: Your residuals over most of the experiment (the beginning points it's higher, like 10%) are around 1-5% of the measured values -- we have no idea what the experimental setup here is, but it's possible that those are entirely within the error bounds anyway and so they are insignificant and the data is linear. I think the analysis isn't really the problem here so much as why OP thinks the analysis is wrong. Plenty of materials have linear relationships like this.

Comment: @tpg2114 that is quite possible - but I never fit a straight line without checking. I agree it is a small effect here, and it begs the question you ask: "why do you think the analysis is wrong?"

Comment: @Floris Thank you for your answer! Because in the next phase, in plotting viscosity from this data and shear stress in the same figure \eta = \sigma / dot{\gamma}, things get strange. I added the Gnuplot's fitting parameters to the body of my question. RMS residuals is 0.0793916, while the asymptomatic standard error is about 2%. Yes, you are right that after the first three point, the thing converges.